# Virtual Loadbalancer based on Virtual IP

Tags: linux, load-balancing, linux-networking, keepalived, bare-metal

I need to setup K8S in HA Mode on hosted Baremetal. If have a vSwitch Network where I can easily assign internal IPs. Is there a Virtual Linuxbased loadbalancer (Active/Passiv) software that allows me to run in L2 network? Where the Passive LB Node assigns the LB IP if the active one is not available in the Network?

edit: is keepalived  maybe the answer to my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keepalived with VRRP should be able to do this, yes.